# Vertically and Horizontally Sizing Cards in Bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried forever to get my bootstrap cards to line up correctly, and now I've finally reverted to creating my own question, so hope someone can help!

The cards originally were all the same width and stacked correctly, however the height was off. They were in a row, but would only stretch to the height of the content.

Now I found a solution which worked for the height by using `d-flex align-items-stretch` in the div. However now when I move to smaller devices, the height matches but the width now stretches with the content. Any suggestions?

```
<section class="row ">
<div class="col-12">
    <h3 class="mb-4">Row Title</h3>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card">
        <div class="card-header">Card 1</div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <p><b>Overview:</b> Text 1<br><br>
            <b>More:</b> Text 2<br><br></p>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary margin" type="button"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> &nbsp;Go</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary margin" type="button"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> &nbsp; Information</button>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<div class="col-lg-6 mb-4 d-flex align-items-stretch">
    <div class="card text-white bg-success">
        <div class="card-header">Card 2</div>
        <div class="card-block">
            <p><b>Overview:</b> Text 2</b></p>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary margin" type="button"><span class="fa fa-check"></span> &nbsp;Go</button>
            <button class="btn btn-secondary margin" type="button"><span class="fa fa-file"></span> &nbsp; Information</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDvW4.jpg

Comment: Basically, I want them always the same size as each other.... not variable sizes... But still scaling to the screen size and content

Comment: The image link is the same code expanded out with slightly more text.

Essentially I want: card1.height = card2.height = card3.height = card4.height AND card1.width = card2.width = card3.width = card4.width (which should be set by the bootstrap columns anyway)

the .height should be determined by the card with max height

Comment: Try using [card decks](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/card/#card-decks)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `w-100` on the cards if you want them to stretch/fill horizontal width.

https://www.codeply.com/go/cwg3qP1ABZ

Also, note that in Bootstrap 4.0.0 `card-block` is now `card-body` for padding in the cards.